# How to write the polynomial with singly-linked list

Tags: c++

Write polynomial program with singly-linked list include degree, evaluate, operator+,*,=-, copy , operator<<,operator>>, using and finished the struct Term.

The professor asked to finish with a singly-linked list, and I tried to change all the words to the linked list type, but it looks strange that I don't know what should changed.

```
#ifndef TERM_H_
#define TERM_H_

#include <iostream>

struct Term {
    int coeff; // Coefficient of term
    int expo; // Exponent of term
    Term * next; // Pointer to next term of Polynomial

    // Constructor
    Term(int init_coeff = 0, int init_expo = 0):
        coeff(init_coeff), expo(init_expo), next(nullptr) {}

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out,
        const Term & a_term) {
        // Write implementation of Term operator<< here.
    }
};

#endif // TERM_H_

#ifndef POLYNOMIAL2_H_# define POLYNOMIAL2_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "term.h"

using namespace std;

class Polynomial {
    public:
        Polynomial();

    Polynomial(vector<int> initial_coefficients, vector<int> initial_exponents);

    int degree() const;
    double evaluate(double x) const;

    friend Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial & left_poly,
        const Polynomial & right_poly);
    friend Polynomial operator * (const Polynomial & left_poly,
        const Polynomial & right_poly);
    friend Polynomial operator = -(const Polynomial & source);

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out_stream,
        const Polynomial & a_poly); // REC'D
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in_stream,
        Polynomial & a_poly); // P'BACK
    void copy(const Polnomial & source);

    private:
        Term * first;
};

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include "polynomial2.h"
#include "term.h"

using namespace std;

Polynomial::Polynomial() {
    size = 0;
    head = new Term;
    head - > coeff = 0;
    head - > expo = 0;
    head - > next = head;
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(std::vector<int> initial_coefficients,
    std::vector<int> initial_exponents) {
    ;
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial() {
    clear();
}

int Polynomial::degree() const {
    return head - > next - > expo;
}

double Polynomial::evaluate(double x) const {
    if () {
        return operator
    }
}

Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial & left_poly,
    const Polynomial & right_poly) {
    void polyadd(struct Node * poly1, struct Node * poly2, struct Node * poly) {
        while (poly1 - > next && poly2 - > next) {
            // If power of 1st polynomial is greater then 2nd, then store 1st as it is 
            // and move its pointer 
            if (poly1 - > pow > poly2 - > pow) {
                poly - > pow = poly1 - > pow;
                poly - > coeff = poly1 - > coeff;
                poly1 = poly1 - > next;
            }

            // If power of 2nd polynomial is greater then 1st, then store 2nd as it is 
            // and move its pointer 
            else if (poly1 - > pow < poly2 - > pow) {
                poly - > pow = poly2 - > pow;
                poly - > coeff = poly2 - > coeff;
                poly2 = poly2 - > next;
            }
            // If power of both polynomial numbers is same then add their coefficients 
            else {
                poly - > pow = poly1 - > pow;
                poly - > coeff = poly1 - > coeff + poly2 - > coeff;
                poly1 = poly1 - > next;
                poly2 = poly2 - > next;
            }
            // Dynamically create new node 
            poly - > next = (struct Node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            poly = poly - > next;
            poly - > next = NULL;
        }
        while (poly1 - > next || poly2 - > next) {
            if (poly1 - > next) {
                poly - > pow = poly1 - > pow;
                poly - > coeff = poly1 - > coeff;
                poly1 = poly1 - > next;
            }
            if (poly2 - > next) {
                poly - > pow = poly2 - > pow;
                poly - > coeff = poly2 - > coeff;
                poly2 = poly2 - > next;
            }
            poly - > next = (struct Node * ) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            poly = poly - > next;
            poly - > next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

Polynomial operator * (const Polynomial & left_poly,
    const Polynomial & right_poly) {
    ;
}

Polynomial operator = -(const Polynomial & source) {
    ;
}

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out_stream,
    const Polynomial & a_poly) // REC'D
{

}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in_stream,
    Polynomial & a_poly) // P'BACK
{

}

void Polynomial::copy(const Polnomial & source) {
    ;
}
```

I don't know how to write the others, and don't know what should changed. It has one struct Term and one class Polynomial, and I don't know when to use which.

Comment: I don't think this compiles (`Polnomial`), you may want to fix that. Don't use `malloc` in c++ code, especially not for objects, you should be using `new`. Evaluate and << should be easy, what problems specifically do you have with those? (how to traverse the list? something else?)

Comment: So what should I changed? Change all the Polynomial:: to struct::? Because it has two .h file so I don't know when need to use the struct Term and when to use the class Polynomial.

Comment: For the polynomial2.h, I think it needs to change the public part, because the professor asked to use singly-link list, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Term is a singly linked list already (`Term * next`) and the main thing that Polynomial needs to contain is one Term (`Term * first`) which it does. So the header files are fine, you just need to implement the stuff. I would add an operator * taking a Polynomial and a Term, it will help with the implementation of the full multiplication of two Polynomials.

Comment: You seem pretty lost, you probably should ask your professor to explain things better.